# How disable tooltip title on GridToolbarFilterButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[GridToolbarContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/596kS.png)

Good afternoon all, when working with mui data-grid a question arose, how can I disable or rename Tooltip on the button with filters in GridToolbarContainer

Comment: please check https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/ for all `props` and `css` used in `data grid` I am unable to understand just by looking at the screenshot. if you could provide codesandbox with example code then i can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but the question is no longer relevant, as I have solved the problem in a slightly different way. But thanks anyway!